# Set Environment variable in .NET Core Console Application from App.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have a .NET Core console application.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    var configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

`environmentName` is always null. How to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in App.config file ?

Answer (score 9):

The OP specified that it's a console app. Starting from .NET Core 3.0, you will have to use DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT instead of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for console apps. For example, the `launchsettings.json` will be this for Development environment:

```
"ConsoleApplication - Development": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

If you use ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, your console host will default to `production` environment.

Even though console apps have no launchsettings.json file in the Properties folder, as soon as you change a property in the console project's properties window, visual studio will automatically create a Properties folder and add a launchsettings.json file.

Comment: I had to modify the launch profile under debug - general before this file appeared.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` first before you run your application or use a default value if environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is null.

The environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` has the default value `Production` in a aspnet-core application, because this is ensured by runtime when variable is not set.

But you have a dotnet application (console) and the variable is not initialized by default.

WINDOWS

```
C:\> set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
C:\> dotnet run ...
```

UNIX

```
$ export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
$ dotnet run ...
```

Comment: Because this is a .NET Console app, there is no ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.  It will have to use DOTNET_ENVIRONEMENT.  Otherwise like you said, the console app will default the environment to `production`.

Answer (score 3):

Asp.net core applications take from the launchsettings.json file when developing in visual studio and when you publish the app will look at the web.config or app.config file. So keep this in mind if you are using visual studio. I'll show you how to set that up aswell. (NOTE: I'm using asp.net core MVC which might be different)

Your launchsettings.json file is located under properties:

[image]

And should look something like this

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58251",
      "sslPort": 44362
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Workorders2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you publish, the app will use your app.config settings. Set it up like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")" value="Production" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then all you need to do is get the environment variable like this:

```cs
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")");
```

Comment: I have mentioned its a console application. Not a ASP.NET Web Application

Answer (score 0):

```
      string value;
      bool toDelete = false;

      // Check whether the environment variable exists.
      value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Test1");
      // If necessary, create it.
      if (value == null)
      {
         Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Test1", "Value1");
         toDelete = true;

         // Now retrieve it.
         value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Test1");
      }
      // Display the value.
      Console.WriteLine($"Test1: {value}\n");

      // Confirm that the value can only be retrieved from the process
      // environment block if running on a Windows system.
      if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Attempting to retrieve Test1 from:");
         foreach (EnvironmentVariableTarget enumValue in
                           Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnvironmentVariableTarget))) {
            value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Test1", enumValue);
            Console.WriteLine($"   {enumValue}: {(value != null ? "found" : "not found")}");
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
      }

      // If we've created it, now delete it.
      if (toDelete) {
         Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Test1", null);
         // Confirm the deletion.
         if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Test1") == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Test1 has been deleted.");
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output if run on a Windows system:
//      Test1: Value1
//
//      Attempting to retrieve Test1 from:
//         Process: found
//         User: not found
//         Machine: not found
//
//      Test1 has been deleted.
//
// The example displays the following output if run on a Unix-based system:
//      Test1: Value1
//
//      Test1 has been deleted.
```

Comment: Its a Console application